# Windows 10 Scheduled Task does not use domain credentials to access network resources

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, cifs, credentials

I have a simple task, which for the purposes of testing, consists of a batch file with two lines:

```
whoami >result1.txt
copy \\server\share\test1.txt C:\Users\xxx\Documents > output.txt 2> error.txt
```

When I run this from an interactive login, it works fine, because I have domain credentials which give me access to the share.

When I run it from Task Scheduler, it fails.  The first command succeeds (and incidentally demonstrates that the scheduled task is running with my identity) but the second command fails, presumably because it isn't using the right credentials to connect.

After the task is run, `error.txt` is empty and `output.txt` contains `"Access is denied."`   There is no useful information in the task history - just `Action Completed` and a `Last Run Result` of `(0x1)` because the copy failed.

The General Options on the Scheduled Task properties are to run with my domain user account and to "Run whether user is logged on or not".  I have tried both with and without "Run with highest privileges" set - doesn't seem to change anything.  I also tried changing the "Configure for" option - again with no effect.  "Do not store password" is not checked - but I tried checking it just for completeness and it doesn't change the behaviour.

On the server side I have checked the Security Event log.  When the command fails I can see an Audit Success Anonymous Logon logon event, an Audit Failure entry which looks like the Anonymous Logon is trying to use SeBackupPrivilege:

```
A privileged service was called.

Subject:
  Security ID:      ANONYMOUS LOGON
  Account Name:     ANONYMOUS LOGON
  Account Domain:       NT AUTHORITY
  Logon ID:     0x180e12c36

Service:
  Server:   Security
  Service Name: -

Process:
  Process ID:   0x4
  Process Name: 

Service Request Information:
  Privileges:       SeBackupPrivilege
```

and then an Audit Success Anonymous Logon session destroyed.

The client is Windows 10, and the server is Windows 2008 R2.  The credentials are a Domain user account in Active Directory.

If I use a different server, a Windows Server 2016 box running IIS and WebDAV, then the task runs fine via the Task Scheduler.  So, going via WebDAV, my credentials are being used, whereas going via CIFS they are not.

Can anyone elucidate why the copy is failing and if there is any workaround? Any next steps for testing? I have got it to work by hard-coding credentials in the batch file but obviously that's not really acceptable.

It was suggested that this policy might be relevant but it's disabled so I don't think it is:

```
Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication

at

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
```

Comment: It would help if the details of the task were provided. In particular, the Security Options of the General tab.

Comment: @GregAskew I have edited those in (thanks).

Comment: What about the option below  "Run whether user is logged on or not"?

Comment: That's unchecked ("Do not store password").  Presumably checking that would make it worse?

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't make any diffference.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "do not store password" if you can save your task with a domain credential. I am thinking if it's any UAC settings prevents it from running. Is there any error code/msg in task history? How about redirect error message to a file in your task? Lastly, the event you included doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: Thanks @strongline I have added those diagnostics to the answer: there no error in the history and the redirect error message shows "Access is Denied.".  The event does seem to be caused by the task.

Comment: The error message (in most part) leads me to believe that you don't have permission to destination (either NTFS permission of UAC). Change your destination to a folder where you have full control explicitly - meaning grant permission directly to the user that is used for task, instead of via group. Just for test purpose.

Comment: But the command works fine when run from an interactive logon.  And the server is reporting not that I don['t have permission but that an Anonymous Logon doesn't have permission.  Also I do have full control.  I created the folder and the file.

Comment: But I tested it anyway and explicit permissions don't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen more anecdotal evidence of permissions behaving differently interactively compared to from a Scheduled Task. And the event log message seems to point towards the fact that it needs the seBackupPrivilige ( which probably really means it wants to change the objects Owner).

Putting the user you run the task under in a built-in local group like Backup Operators on the target server might do the trick ( don't have a test bed to test this, but if unsure start with local admin on both servers and then use elimination).

In theory you could also use the domain GPO to set similar permissions for the specific user or even better their group.

EDITED: Have you tried to omit or change the error output? The security event could be a red-herring ( NTLM auth will always have a failed anonymous entry for instance).

If I run your script it errors out in a scheduled task because there is no path in front of > output.txt and 2> error.txt - but this works:

```
copy \\two.moh.local\test\test1.txt C:\temp\ > c:\temp\output.txt 2> c:\temp\error.txt
```

Your script will work if you run it from a command prompt or by double clicking because it will use the parent directory, that works differently when not running interactively (I'm assuming it tried to write somewhere where domain admin does have permissions while your user does not).

Comment: On the server, the domain account has full control.  The problem seems to be that the user accessing the file on the server is Anonymous Logon, not the domain account that the Scheduled Task is running under.

Comment: To clafify a little - NTFS full control or as in the user is Local Admin/Power User/Backup Operator? 

There is a difference between a NTFS ACL ( who can access the data) and a Security Privilege ( who may do what within the Windows OS). Others have explained it way better than I can - for instance: https://medium.com/@grzegorztworek/ive-got-the-power-4f44b1998c88

Why exactly this behaviour is different when doing this interactively I don't know - but I have seen it before ( also in other question on ServerFault).

Comment: I would still suggest making the user member of a local group - which will grant them the seBackupPrivilege inside Windows on that machine - and seeing if it makes a difference.

Comment: OK - I added the user to the Local Backup Operators group and it didn't fix the problem.  And the event in the Security Event Log is unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

First of all "Task Scheduler Error 0x1" his hard to debug and need to try a couple of solutions in order to find the reason on your environment.

After i read the question and the asnwers i will sugest to:

1. Try to explicitly state all paths used in the scripts or batches files. Don’t use short path. Edit the destination path C:\Users\xxx\Documents  to something like D:\test.
2. Try to include full path on error and output files.

Also i will sugest to check the options at "action tab". Try to use quotes on paths with spaces.

You can also find valuable informacion about return error 0x1 on this [source](https://www.get-itsolutions.com/task-scheduler-0x1/)